nmap затяжное сканирование
sudo nmap -sS 192.168.0.1/24 занимает огромное количество времени. top показывает, что nmap уходит в сон (S).
Кто знает, как nmap сделать постоянно активным во время сканирования ?

Это нормально, nmap отправляет пакеты и ждёт ответа на них, ускорить это невозможно
